# How to upgrade the gradle in a react native app

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I am working on a react-native project which has gradle version of **4.4** (can be found in project folder /android/.gradle/4.4) but I want to upgrade it to latest one which is **6.0.1**. Please help me

I want to change the version in red to 6.0.1(latest) not the one in white

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Inside android>gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties

update the distributionUrl to your specific gradle like :

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip`

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: okay after changing the link how will it be updated the folder is still there.

Comment: see, finally you want to make a build right? when you next execute the commands for building APK, it will take this gradle version. 
try in android folder ./gradlew clean and then ./gradlew assembleDebug

Comment: did it help @joedenly

Answer (score 3):

Change gradle version here:

> android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

`in:distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip`

Then you need to change the plugin version in:

> android/build.gradle

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
```

You can see the gradle version for each plugin here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle

Comment: Doing this for 7.2 yields `Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.`

Comment: @fullStackChris Check here the version you need: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google

Answer (score 0):

In android/build.gradle you have to edit this line

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.y.z'

Change x.y.z with the version you want. Edit it with Android Studio then click Sync now

Comment: but it's version in my  config is 3.0.0 which is different from the above gradle version. These are two different things

Comment: Yes, if you were right, I also want to know why the difference.